# Replace values on multiple worksheets using Office Scripts

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, performance, office-scripts

This script is currently taking 45 sec to run, Any thoughts on enhancing the performance on this?

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  try {
  const sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
  const breakCol = sheet.getUsedRange(true);
      const values = breakCol.getValues();
      for (let row of values) {
        for (let cell of row) {
          breakCol.replaceAll("Pass", "", { completeMatch: true });
          breakCol.replaceAll("Fail", "", { completeMatch: true });
          breakCol.replaceAll("Skip", "", { completeMatch: true });
        }
      }
     }
}
catch (e) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best performing way took 1.3 secs to execute:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheets();
  const activeWorksheetcount = workbook.getWorksheets().length;
  for (let i = 0; i < activeWorksheetcount; i++) {
    selectedSheet[i].replaceAll("Pass", "", { completeMatch: true, matchCase:true });
    selectedSheet[i].replaceAll("Fail", "", { completeMatch: true, matchCase:true });
    selectedSheet[i].replaceAll("Skip", "", { completeMatch: true, matchCase:true });
  }
}
```